# Animate a 3D matrix with Matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a 3D matrix of shape (100,50,50), e.g.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.random(100,50,50)
```

And I want to create an animation that shows each of the 2D slices of size (50,50) as a heatmap or `imshow`

e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(data[0,:,:])
plt.show()
```

would display the 1st 'frame' of this animation. I'd like to also have this display in a Jupyter Notebook. I am currently following [this](http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-notebooks/) tutorial for inline notebook animations being displayed as a html video, but I can't figure out how to replace the 1D line data with a slice of my 2D array.

I know I need to create a plot element, an initialisation function and an animate function. Following that example, I've tried:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim((0, 50))
ax.set_ylim((0, 50))

im, = ax.imshow([])

def init():
    im.set_data([])
    return (im,)

# animation function. This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    data_slice = data[i,:,:]
    im.set_data(i)
    return (im,)

# call the animator. blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

But I'm getting various errors whatever I try, mostly associated with the line `im, = ax.imshow([])`

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several issues:

1. You have a lot of missing imports.
2. `numpy.random.random` takes a tuple as input, not 3 arguments
3. `imshow` needs an array as input, not an empty list.
4. `imshow` returns an `AxesImage`, which cannot be unpacked. Hence no `,` on the assignment.
5. `.set_data()` expects the data, not the framenumber as input.

Complete code:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

data = np.random.rand(100,50,50)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim((0, 50))
ax.set_ylim((0, 50))

im = ax.imshow(data[0,:,:])

def init():
    im.set_data(data[0,:,:])
    return (im,)

# animation function. This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    data_slice = data[i,:,:]
    im.set_data(data_slice)
    return (im,)

# call the animator. blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```