# I have a list of 3D coordinates over time, that is, a video of points. How can I visualize this in Python?

Tags: python, data-visualization, mplot3d, open3d, qtquick3d

So the data might look like:

```
at time 0 : [(8,8,9), (2,4,5), ...]
at time 1 : [(3,5,1), (7,4,3), ...]
...
at time N : ...
```

I need to visualize these points in a video using Python.

Comment: it this your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118598/3d-animation-using-matplotlib OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630340/animate-a-3d-matrix-with-matplotlib-in-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it would be easiest to use OpenCV library ([tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html)). Covert your data into a series of Mat (image) objects, and display using its standard GUI frame by frame.